# Referencing other projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects in Eclipse (I'm using STS) - one Java application (p1) and one Dynamic web project with Spring (p2), both created as "Spring project template" in Eclipse. I'd like to reference p1 from p2. Always I did this through project properties/Java build path and in "Projects" tab add p1 and check this project in "Order and Export" tab. Also I did in this case, but when I run p2 in Eclipse (Run on server), bootstrap fails because of Class not found exception (class from p1).

I think this behaviour has nothing to do with maven config, am I right? This is just Eclipse thing, so I have no clue, why the p1 project is not referenced.

Adding dependency to pom.xml and generate war with maven and run outside is not way for me, I need to run it in IDE.

Comment: I guess you need to add project dependency in pom.xml... Have you tried to install maven plugin for the same in eclipse?

Comment: I tried this too, but I think - this is not problem, because in Eclipse are project correctly bound together (imports in p2 are correct, no error). But exporting project and running it on server does not work (when I export .war with eclipse, classes from p1 are missing, even though p1 is marked for export).

Comment: In case of added dependency to pom.xml running ends with ContextLoadListener, which is unerstandable, because both are spring application and somehow bot getting started and this is not way I want to go - I just need a few clases from p1.

Comment: OK, I figured it out - there is "Deployment Assembly" option in project properties and my p1 was missing here, so I added it here and everything works fine now!! (until update maven dependencies is performed of course)